# What do to when the moderation system of a site fails

Tags: discussion, edits, moderation

On [Parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/), a moderator has taken it upon themselves to start mass editing answers, blowing away as much as 50% or more of peoples posts because it was deemed that this information "shouldn't be there." The moderator believes that the huge portions of the answers deleted were off topic or were detrimental in some way, so rather than allowing the community to use the tools put in place for self regulation (voting, discussion), they've chosen this route, even on highly upvoted answers. [Here](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/22927/how-can-i-convince-my-parents-to-accept-my-approach-on-school) is an example.

A conversation was brought up on [the meta](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/975/what-to-do-about-overreaching-moderation) about moderator overreach. There appears to be a strong disagreement between the community members participating in the meta discussion and the moderators. What can be done in a situation where moderators and the (vocal) members of a community appear to have irreconcilable differences?

Comment: Required reading: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing/

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks, I'll read. I'm not new to the network and I don't get in a huff when people edit my stuff (anymore haha), I understand it's an important part of how the network stays healthy, but I've never seen such massive editing. It's on such a scale in some cases that they're not edits, they're complete rewrites, imo.

Comment: The critical question is, *do the **authors** object?*

Comment: How is this different than [a 1000 rep user](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) making the changes?

Comment: Wow.  I've deleted the answer I gave due to the edits and will have to reconsider my participation on that site.

Comment: And from meta.parenting: [what to do about overreaching moderation?](http://meta.parenting.stackexchange.com/q/975/7274)... and apparently the key meta policy question at work: [What should we advise when one disagrees with the premise of a question?](http://meta.parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/123/what-should-we-advise-when-one-disagrees-with-the-premise-of-a-question) and more recently addressed in [Isn't “You're Wrong” an “answer”?](http://meta.parenting.stackexchange.com/a/974/7274)... and [another meta question on it](http://meta.parenting.stackexchange.com/q/969/7274).

Comment: I'm particularly annoyed that I was never notified of these edits, nor given a chance to alter my response if it was against site policy.  It appears these changes were made without trying to educate the people answering at all, almost sneakily and invisibly.  This is troubling on a number of fronts.

Comment: I don't see this as a moderation issue. It's an editing one. Aside from 'protecting' the question (which isn't part of this meta post), the moderator isn't doing anything differently that someone with edit permissions is able to do.

Comment: @AdamDavis Moderator edits are bumped as well, there are no exceptions to that rule

Comment: I see [a notification here](http://stackexchange.com/users/2114/adam-davis?tab=inbox), @Adam? Regardless, you should be able to roll it back if the edit bothers you.

Comment: @Adam I'm with you, I stopped using that site a while ago due to over strict moderation I don't like and not enough incentive for me to start a war over this.

Comment: @JonW the issue here is the amount of edits. Regular user will very unlikely have "courage" to remove stuff from so many posts just like that, because he feels it's off topic. Removing "thanks" and "hello" is one thing, totally changing people's posts is another thing. It's plain rude.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Talk to the moderator, preferably on your per-site meta. Not so much about the acts of moderation itself at first, but about the issue itself. Sometimes heavy-handed moderation is appropriate, but there needs to be a conversation about it on meta if there are disagreements about the issue.

Figure out why these large edits were made, and get a consensus in the community if that is the way the site should work. From your post I gather that the moderators have a consensus, I don't know how much this was discussed by the community. I'd spend a bit more time discussing and understanding the reasons for the heavy editing. Maybe the moderators will convince the community, or the other way around.

There are some policies that inevitably drive away some users, the one I'm most familiar with is the citation requirement for answers on Skeptics. It is a very heavy-handed and pretty blunt instrument, but it is necessary for the site and we did discuss this at length before we actually started to remove any answers that violated that rule.

If you feel that there are irreconcilable differences between the community and the moderators, you can contact SE and ask them to take a look and maybe intervene.

Answer (score 6):

As described in [Delay for deleting answers after being advised of need for improvement](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/972/7274), questions that hit the Hot Network Questions get increased scrutiny. This is because such questions are shown to the entire network and often bring in people who are unfamiliar with the norms of the site.  Its one thing for someone to need to go doing substantial edits on a question that has a hundred or so views in a week, its another thing for the question to be one that has six *thousand* views in two days on a small, pseudo-graduated site (or however one should refer to sites that aren't beta but haven't gone all the way).

Thus, (and I'm guessing here) the moderator team has decided that it is necessary to make sure that *all* the answers are in line with the site's policies (in particular [Isn't "You're Wrong" an "answer"?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/973/isnt-youre-wrong-an-answer/974#974) and [What should we advise when one disagrees with the premise of a question?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123/what-should-we-advise-when-one-disagrees-with-the-premise-of-a-question)) so that the newcomers to the site can be shown the best practices within the site and if they leave an answer, the existing answers provide guidance to the OP on how to best answer it.